# Bootstrap 4 .card-deck messes up column width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, width

Notice the width of the two upper cards are not as wide as the lower one

[image]

[View source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc90o.png)

**source code:**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="card-deck m-b-1">

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src=
        "http://lorempixel.com/318/180/sports/5">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below
        as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little
        bit longer.</p><a class="card-link" href="#">Läs mer</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top" src=
        "http://lorempixel.com/318/180/sports/7">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural
        lead-in to additional content.</p><a class="card-link" href="#">Läs
        mer</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried changing up the rows and column structure and not using columns at all but no success!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that's not messed up, that's the intended view. There's 2 cards within the card-deck so there's 2 columns. To have the upper 2 cards the same width as the lower one, take them out of the card-deck div.